# How to translate "When" in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm looking to understand how to represent "When" in a propositional logic.
For example:

1: "I buy food when I get paid." Would the order of this matter, say "When I get paid, I buy food"?

Would this be,  Food -> Paid?

2: "When I go to Walmart to buy food, I don't buy onions"

Would this be   (Walmart & Food) -> -Onions?

3: "I always go to Walmart on Saturday, but I never go any other day"

Would this just be Walmart -> Saturday, or does a statement like this also need to include  -Saturday -> -Walmart?

It might be easier to give answers just using variables such as x,y,z etc, but I made up some examples to try understand it better

Comment: Apart from this being a very odd exercise - I presume it is: paid -> food

Comment: I'm not a native English, but I'd translate it to ''if''.

Comment: @Imago The examples themselves I just made up to try explain the question better, do you think it would be better if I just used arbitrary variables like X,Y,Z etc?

Comment: The suggestions given are fine, but there is not always a direct read over from natural language to formal logic: when could mean "whenever" but there could, in natural language, be an implied "only" as "I only buy food when I get paid" and that is just one of the slippery ambiguities which formal language is explicitly designed to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"B when A" is "if A, then B".

Thus you are quite right: : "I buy food when I get paid" will be: "If I get paid, then I buy food".

Buy in symbols it is: $\text{GetPaid} \to \text {BuyFood}$.

The second is "When A, then B", and in this case is: "If A, then B".

Thus: $\text {GoWalmart} \to \lnot \text {BuyOnions}$

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you could answer the following question too:
"James watched a film. It must have been at the cinema."
If we have Film(x), Watched(x,y) and Location(z), is it simply just:

∃x(Film(x) & Watched(James,x) & Location(cinema))
I didn't want to make a question because I thought it wouldn't be big enough. The part I'm stuck on is how to interpret "must have"